# How many ways can you paint a regular Decagon with q colors? Solve with Burnside's lemma

Tags: group-theory, coloring, symmetry, fixed-points

How many ways can you paint a regular Decagon with q colors?
I need to solve it with Burnside's lemma.
So far I managed to find only 2 symmetries, the identity, and this one.
I believe I miss the method, can someone solve, and try to explain how did he solve it?
[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the Dihedral group?

Comment: Hint: a square has 8 symmetries, not just 2.

Comment: You actually have some of the other symmetries drawn on your image.

Comment: I found no other method beside brute forcing all combinations.

Comment: No one is saying so, but I imagine we're all talking about a *regular* decagon.